# How to insert a "%" symbol in a label, python

Tags: python, label, symbols

I have been trying to create a label in a plot that includes the "%" symbol, but I keep getting different error messages.

What I want is a label that shows something like: **25% -> xxx**

The line of code where I try to do it is something like this:

`plt.step(sorted_data, 1. * np.arange(len(data_RS_2367)) / (len(data_RS_2367) - 1), label = 'RS_2380, 25 \% \to %.2f' %val_2380)`

It's the first time a ask anything here, I'm sorry if I missed any important information.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: use double `%%` to put percent - `'%s%% -> xxx' % (25,)`

Comment: you can also use new string formatting and then you can use single `%` - `'{}% -> xxx'.format(variable)` or `f-string` - `f'{variable}% -> xxx'`

Comment: thanks for the advice @furas !! and for solving the problem!